# reindex Catalog URL Rewrites in magento never ends

Tags: magento, indexing

I've imported 6K categories and 16K products to magento using a custom import profile.
When I'm trying to reindex everything works except for 'Catalog URL Rewrites' that keep showing PROCESSING but never completes.

log and exceptions files don't show anything.

Is there something I can do to make the index work?
Can I just ignore this index and not use it? (I don't know what it does).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort of ignore this index if you do not care about pretty, search engine "friendly" URL's. The products will still appear in the catalog but will have their default "Zend Framework" type URL (/catalog/product/view/id/123)

My store has 150,000+ SKUs in two store views. On my development environment it took almost two weeks to complete.

The best way to determine how fast it is running is to look at the core_url_rewrite database table. It appears that the process starts at product ID 1 in store ID 1 and looks to make sure all of its URLs exist and creates the ones that do not yet exist.

For me the reason it took so long was that it had to go through my entire catalog twice to make all the URLs. One thing I did notice was that this process creates a ton of URLs that are completely unnecessary. In our store easily 90% of our products belong to a configurable product so their visibility is set to "Not Visible Individually" so they never would need to have a URL. This index creates those URLs anyways.

Hopefully this will shed some light on to how this URL works. I would keep an eye on that database table so you sorta know how far the process has come. I would also seriously consider running the reindex process for the command line. I have included a link that explains how to do this (disclosure: it's from my blog)

http://overlycaffeinated.com/2011/02/when-reindexing-in-magento-fails-use-the-command-line/

Comment: Great blog post. 18,000+ products in my store - Catalog URL indexing had been running over night and some more . Used your method in shell and it finished in less than 5 minutes. Genius!

Comment: Heads up on using the CLI to run the indexer: You'll want to make sure that you run the correct binary of PHP as the correct user. For instance, on a Bitnami Magento server you would need to run `sudo -u daemon /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php ./shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url` This will be different for each server, but make sure that you're not just using `php` without considering what user you're logged in as.

Comment: FYI, the blog post url is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

My own attempt of reindexing URL rewrites was with 10,000 products and it took me like an Hour and Half to finish up.

this link will help you do it from Command Line , which is preferable than doing it from the same Magento admin panel.

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/340-magento-14-cronjobs

Make sure you read the part about skipping some basic configuration when facing memory limits , this is the one i usually use.

Comment: This link is redirecting to the index page of the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need catalog URL rewrites to make your catalog work properly. How long are you letting it run for? There's a really substantial amount of data to be written to it...

If you cannot make it work programmatically, it may be possible to shove the data into the table manually and force the index to feel refreshed? Caveat emptor, I have not tried this.

Comment: I'm waiting more than an hour until I'm getting an error:
An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite.
I think it's from:
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Url.php

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem, the server that I am running this on is a FreeBSD server.  With the help of the sample of the above code I was able to get the issue to resolve buy running the following command in the shell.

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/magento/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url

It runs very quickly and resolved my issue.  I then created a cron for this to run every 6 hours on my server.

Comment: `php -f ./indexer.php -- reindex catalog_url`

Comment: Mine is definitely not running very quickly...20 minutes plus now. ⏳

Answer (score -1):

You can **reindex** using **command** line it will reduce 75% of load and your magento admin panel working as normal while reindexing.