# Magento Indexing locks tables

Tags: magento

I am having issues while indexing in running on Magento EE 1.12. Some of the tables are locked during indexing and customers are unable to complete the order. They receive SQL error when submitting their orders.

Indexing is also taking too long.

Any ideas?

Steve

Comment: What are you reindexing and how often?

Comment: I am re-indexing over 4000 products and have 5 stores. Mainly URL rewrites in taking too long.

Comment: How many products 'visible' vs 'not shown individally'? Have you cleared out, i.e. truncated the url rewrte table and when do you run this reindexing?

Comment: All the products are visible. We have tried running it after truncating the core_url_rewrites but still taking too long and locks table for a very long time.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385500/reindex-catalog-url-rewrites-in-magento-never-ends

Comment: This is a different issue. We are getting following error when customer is trying to place the order during indexing process: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should never have table locks occurring. Can you verify your tables are set to InnoDB and not MySIAM.
MySIAM is what would lock the whole table, while InnoDB should lock only the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the tables and all the tables in magento are InnoDB. Still trying to figure out why this is happening. Is there a way to check the db is there is anything wrong or optimizing it.

Comment: The error "There is a problem, please try again later" appears as a dialog box when I click on Confirm order during indexing process. I also receive an email with subject line "Payment transaction failed".

Comment: Further to my last comment, we are using Remote MySQL server which is connected with a cross connection cable with the app server.